# Laravel Elastic Search Getting error "No alive nodes found in your cluster"

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch, ddev

I want to integrate Elasticsearch into my Laravel project hence i have setup Elastic search inside my Local machine and it is working fine,

I am using

```
ddev
```

as a development environment

then I have installed Laravel Version 9 and elastic seach package using

```
composer require cviebrock/laravel-elasticsearch
```

Note: when I am running `http://localhost:9200/` it is showing successful response hence elastic search is installed perfectly

when I try to use below code

```
$response = Elasticsearch::search([
                'index' => 'books',
                'body'  => [
                    'query' => [
                        'multi_match' => [
                            'query' => "Dormouse,' the.",
                            'fields' => [
                                'title'
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]);
```

I got an error

```
Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\NoNodesAvailableException : No alive nodes found in your cluster
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I recommend that you use the DDEV add-on `ddev-elasticsearch`, which will get you going faster. `ddev get drud/ddev-elasticsearch`. Follow the instructions at https://github.com/drud/ddev-elasticsearch to learn more. You'll be a lot better off with elasticsearch running inside DDEV as in this solution.

From there, you'll need to know how to configure Laravel, but you should be able to do fine with it.